# How to handle exceptions when subscribing with Actions in RXJava

Tags: java, exception, rx-java, reactive-programming

Here is a simple example:

```
Completable c = Completable.create(new CompletableOnSubscribe() {
    @Override
    public void subscribe(@NonNull CompletableEmitter e) throws Exception {
        throw new Exception("Oh No!");
    }
});

try {
    c.subscribe(new Action() {
        @Override
        public void run() throws Exception {
            Timber.v("It's ok");
        }
    });
}
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    Timber.v("Error");
}
```

In this case, I would have expected the exception to be caught however it causes the app to crash. So how are we supposed to handle the exception thrown by the inner class method?

I know that we could handle this differently by subscribing with a `CompletableObserver` but that adds extra verbosity that I'd like to avoid and I feel that there must be a way to handle this kind of Exception other the Action consumer wouldn't be very useful.

Comment: There is an [overload](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Completable.html#subscribe-io.reactivex.functions.Action-io.reactivex.functions.Consumer-) taking an error consumer you can handle the exception. Also try-catch around a such reactive components don't work as they signal error instead of (re-)throwing them in general.

Comment: Could you provide an example, I'm find it hard to visualize what you mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all RxJava already has a mechanism to catch Exceptions, But you need to implement `onError` Action.

have a look at following code:

```
Completable c = Completable.create(new CompletableOnSubscribe() {
    @Override 
    public void subscribe(@NonNull CompletableEmitter e) throws Exception {
        throw new Exception("Oh No!");
    } 
})

c.subscribe(new Action() { 
    @Override 
    public void run() throws Exception {
        Timber.v("It's ok"); 
    } 
}, new Consumer<Throwable>() {  // Second argument is onError Action
    @Override 
    public void accept(Throwable e) { 
        // Handle you exception here.
        Timber.v("Error"); 
    } 
});
```

Let's come to why your code is unable to catch exception even when you have put everything in try-catch, because exception being thrown is instance of `RuntimeException` class and your are catching instance of `Exception` class.
Try using `RuntimeException`, thrown exception should be caught then.

But it is not ideal way to catch exception instead use `onError` action described in above code snippet. And if your code is throwing Runtime exception then convert it into `Exception` using try-catch inside Observables.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is an overload for handling errors:

```
c.subscribe(new Action() {
    @Override
    public void run() throws Exception {
        Timber.v("It's ok");
    }
}, new Consumer<Throwable>() {
    @Override
    public void accept(Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Timber.v("Error");
    }
});
```